# Initialising OpenCV-VideoCapture-class in another multithreading class

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, video-capture

Im trying to initialise VideoCapture capturedevice once in my multithreading program. Once initialised it should serve in the acquireImage-thread as the image-buffer, which is filled by a webcam. 
The following code shows me a "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (func != 0) in cv::imshow"-error during runtime, which means VideoCapture capturedevice is never really initialised and therefore imshow doesnt have necessary data, but why?

The code was constructed based on this question: [Correctly using mutex in OpenCL-OpenCV-Realtime-Threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315021/correctly-using-mutex-in-opencl-opencv-realtime-threads) Basically it uses two threads, one processes images originating from a usb-webcam and the second will find faces on those images...but does nothing at the moment for code-simplicity.

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned int uint;

class FaceDetector
{
mutex imageLock, facesLock;
condition_variable imageAqcuired;
bool newImageAvailable;

Mat _img;
Mat _imgToWorkOn;
Mat _faceImages;
bool quit;

VideoCapture captureDevice;
int device_id;
FaceDetector (int _device_id);

void acquireImage()
{
while (!quit)
{

    unique_lock<mutex> ulock(imageLock);
    imageAqcuired.wait(ulock,[&](){return !newImageAvailable;}); //only take new image after current one was consumed

    Mat captureFrame;
    captureDevice>>captureFrame;
    transpose(captureFrame,captureFrame);
    flip(captureFrame,captureFrame,1);
    _img = captureFrame.clone();

    ulock.unlock();
    newImageAvailable = true;
    imageAqcuired.notify_one(); //notify that a new image is available
}
}
void processImage()
{
while (!quit)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> ulock(imageLock);
    imageAqcuired.wait(ulock,[&](){return newImageAvailable;}); //wait untill a new image is available
    _imgToWorkOn = _img.clone();
    ulock.unlock();
    newImageAvailable = false;
    imageAqcuired.notify_one(); //notify the current image can be replaced by a newer one
    unique_lock<mutex> lockFace(facesLock);
    //arbeit
    lockFace.unlock();
}
}

public:
FaceDetector() : newImageAvailable(false) {}
void start() {
quit = false;
thread t1(&FaceDetector::acquireImage,this);
t1.detach();
thread t2(&FaceDetector::processImage,this);
t2.detach();
}
void stop() {
quit = true;
}
Mat getImage() {
if (quit)
    return Mat();
lock_guard<mutex> lock(imageLock);
return _img;
}

Mat getProcessedImage() {
if (quit)
    return Mat();
lock_guard<mutex> lock(facesLock);
return _faceImages;
}

};

FaceDetector::FaceDetector(int _device_id)
{

device_id = _device_id;
captureDevice.open(device_id);
captureDevice.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,620);             //erst jetzt cam.set weil sonst system-pause nicht funzt
captureDevice.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480);

}

int main()
{
bool quit(false);
FaceDetector faceDet;
faceDet.start();
thread input([](bool &quitFlag) { getchar(); quitFlag = true; },ref(quit)); //stop on user press Enter
input.detach();
while (!quit) {


Mat img = faceDet.getImage();
Mat imgc = img.clone();

imshow("links", imgc);

/*
imgs = faceDet.getProcessedImage();
Mat imgsc = imgs.clone();

imshow("gsichter", imgsc);
*/
waitKey(30);
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(33)); //no need to show more than 30 fps...
}
faceDet.stop();
return 0;
}
```

Edit: I tried to include your answer, still getting "Opencv Assertion Error in imshow".

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned int uint;

class FaceDetector
{
mutex imageLock, facesLock;
condition_variable imageAqcuired;
bool newImageAvailable;

Mat _img;
Mat _imgToWorkOn;
Mat _faceImages;
bool quit;

VideoCapture captureDevice;
int device_id;

void acquireImage()
{
while (!quit)
{

    unique_lock<mutex> ulock(imageLock);
    imageAqcuired.wait(ulock,[&](){return !newImageAvailable;}); //only take new image after current one was consumed

    Mat captureFrame;
    captureDevice>>captureFrame;
    //transpose(captureFrame,captureFrame);
    //flip(captureFrame,captureFrame,1);
    _img = captureFrame.clone();

    ulock.unlock();
    newImageAvailable = true;
    imageAqcuired.notify_one(); //notify that a new image is available
}
}
void processImage()
{
while (!quit)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> ulock(imageLock);
    imageAqcuired.wait(ulock,[&](){return newImageAvailable;}); //wait untill a new image is available
    _imgToWorkOn = _img.clone();
    ulock.unlock();
    newImageAvailable = false;
    imageAqcuired.notify_one(); //notify the current image can be replaced by a newer one
    unique_lock<mutex> lockFace(facesLock);
    //arbeit
    lockFace.unlock();
}
}

public:

FaceDetector() : newImageAvailable(false) {}
void start() {
quit = false;
thread t1(&FaceDetector::acquireImage,this);
t1.detach();
thread t2(&FaceDetector::processImage,this);
t2.detach();
}
void stop() {
quit = true;
}
Mat getImage() {
if (quit)
    return Mat();
lock_guard<mutex> lock(imageLock);
return _img;
}

Mat getProcessedImage() {
if (quit)
    return Mat();
lock_guard<mutex> lock(facesLock);
return _faceImages;
}

FaceDetector::FaceDetector(int _device_id)
{
VideoCapture captureDevice;
device_id = _device_id;
captureDevice.open(device_id);
captureDevice.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,620);             //erst jetzt cam.set weil sonst system-pause nicht funzt
captureDevice.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480);
}

};

int main()
{
bool quit(false);
FaceDetector faceDet(0);
faceDet.start();
thread input([](bool &quitFlag) { getchar(); quitFlag = true; },ref(quit)); //stop on     user press Enter
input.detach();
while (!quit) {


Mat img = faceDet.getImage();
Mat imgc = img.clone();

imshow("links", imgc);

/*
imgs = faceDet.getProcessedImage();
Mat imgsc = imgs.clone();

imshow("gsichter", imgsc);
*/
waitKey(30);
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(33)); //no need to show more than 30 fps...
}
faceDet.stop();
return 0;
}
```

I also tried following code, but still getting said Assertion Error.

```
public:
FaceDetector(int device_id) : newImageAvailable(false) {}
....
void init() {
VideoCapture captureDevice;
captureDevice.open(device_id);
captureDevice.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,620);             //erst jetzt cam.set weil sonst system-pause nicht funzt
captureDevice.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480);
}

int main()
{
FaceDetector faceDet(0);
faceDet.init();
faceDet.start();
}
```

Comment: the VideoCapture *is* already running in a thread of its own. you won't gain anything, wrapping another thread around it. if you're doing cascade-detection, *that*'s a candidate.

Answer (score 1):

In `main()` function You are not creating object `faceDet` using constructor `FaceDetector::FaceDetector(int _device_id)` but you are using default constructor. This means you are not opening `captureDevice` at all.

**Edit for correction**

In the declaration, make `FaceDetector::FaceDetector(int _device_id)` public.
Now in `main()`, create object `faceDet` using this constructor, you need to call like this:

```
FaceDetector faceDet(0); // I have taken 0 as as default camera ID, you can add other value like 1 or 2 etc depending the choice of camera too.
```

This should be be working now, please let me know of any problem should you face.

Comment: Could you please include your suggestion in the code or give me a code snippet? I thought a constructor for a class has to have the same name as the class and therefore no multiple private/public-constructors could be used...i dont really know how to include your answer as code because i think then i would have to include my initialising-videocapture-class in the default-constructor? I never really used self-made-classes before (functions always sufficed my needs) and therefore im depended on your help in this case. The examples in the net always just show simple stuff like changing integers..

Comment: I tried including your suggestion, but im still getting the Assertion Error. Camera is always connected, so the code is still faulty.

Comment: Ofcourse, you're code can have some more bugs. I am on travel now. You should go step wise in your code. First implement single threaded and verify then go for multi thread. Also, post the exact error you are getting to understand the problem.

Comment: Hi @Echo88, I am back to work :) Please share the exact error you are seeing, also, first get it working in single-threaded.